# Xcode Editor Hide Change pop up menu has a keyboard shortcut but the symbol following the command key isn't obvious

Tags: xcode, keyboard-shortcuts

Not a code question but an Xcode UI question...

[image]

One might guess that to hide a version change you might choose command + space but that isn't right.

Searched the Key Bindings and didn't find anything that matched.

Anybody know what the offical key is?

Have looked in Settings > Key Binding and searched.

Comment: What version of Xcode? How did you get the "Hide Change" option? I only see the other two (Stage/Discard) options.

Comment: 15.0.1 - you have made a change to your source file? The shows the Show Change option.

Comment: That's really odd, isn't it? I even went so far as to disable spotlight to see if it was overriding Cmd-Space. FWIW, Cmd-Opt-Shift-Return toggles the side-by-side diff view, which answers the "what was the change?" option in a different way.

Comment: It's mouse click ... now that was obvious.